# Make Background Black Except for Single Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Width="100" Margin="20">
                <CheckBox x:Name="cbFoo1" Content="Foo"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Foo"/>
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="100" Margin="20">
                <CheckBox x:Name="cbFoo2" Content="Foo"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Foo"/>
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Fill="#BF000000" x:Name="rOverlay"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to make a function `foo` with argument `argControls()` that makes `rOverlay` cover every control in the window except `argControls()`. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Move all controls to the back, put the overlay on top and move the desired control to the front?

Comment: I want to do it from code-behind. Also if the controls are in a `StackPanel` or `DockPanel`, it won't work.

Comment: You're right, I was too quick to comment there! Sorry!

Comment: And how about hittesting (clicking on controls) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I will disable them from code-behind.

Comment: No, this is not how you do whatever you are attempting to do.  What you need to do is [edit] your question and then, in simple terms and perhaps with mockup images, describe the goal you are attempting to accomplish (i.e., I wish to have an in-form modal dialog that blocks all other content except for form controls) and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the visibility of the control to Collapsed when you want to hide them.

Comment: Nope. That's not what my question is.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not completely clear what you need to do. Are you trying to change the background colour of your controls or actually hide them so that the user can't see them?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - Draw Order

While a bit of a hack, perhaps the simplest way to accomplish this is to place controls that you wish covered before the rectangle and controls that you wish visible after the rectangle.

One step better (and not a hack) would to use the `Panel.ZIndex` property instead. This allows you to control the order that the UI elements are drawn regardless of the order that they are defined. This would be accomplished by setting the `Panel.ZIndex` as follows:

- rOverlay to some arbitrary value (like 1)
- controls to be covered to something lower than rOverlay (like 0)
- controls to be visible to something higher than rOverlay (like 2)

It should however be noted that any transparent regions of your controls will still display the black rectangle behind them. This can either be specifying a background colour or by using another option presented here.

### Option 2 - Clipping

Another more complex method involves setting the Clip property of the rectangle to a geometry that only includes the regions that you wish filled. This would likely be accomplished by using an instance of [CombinedGeometry class with the CombineMode of Exclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.geometrycombinemode.aspx). This would prevent the rectangle from drawing anything over regions outside the clipped region.